# Fizzbuzz game with for loop

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, fizzbuzz

I'm trying to do a function that'll print the numbers between 1-27 in my console.log.

When a number can be divided by 3, it should replace the number with "Fizz"
When a number can be divided by 5, replace it with "Buzz".
If the number can be divided by both 3 and 5, replace it with "Fizzbuzz"

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz)

This is my code:

```
 var fizzbuzz = function(start,stop) {
    for (var x=1;x <= stop; x++)
        var string =',';
    if (x%3 == 0) {
            string += 'Fizz';
    }
    if (x%5 ==  0){
        string += 'Buzz';
    }
    if (x%5 && x%3){
        string += 'Fizzbuzz';
    }
    return string;
};
```

Console.log is giving me "," and I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

Just to clarify.
I want my answer to print out `1,2,Fizz,4,Buzz,Fizz,7,8,Fizz,Buzz,11,Fizz,13,14,Fizz Buzz,16,17,Fizz,19,Buzz,Fizz,22,23,Fizz,Buzz,26,Fizz` and so on depending on 'stop' in the If-statement.

Comment: Because your for loop does not have brackets, which means only var string = ','; is executed inside the loop

Comment: Are brackets {} or []? I would also like to add that I'm still very new to javascript!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valentins comment is correct, you do need to add brackets around your loop.
You are however also redefining the string var in every iteration of the loop.

The last if also makes the output a bit wrong as for example 15 would hit all 3 statements and print FizzBuzzFizzBuzz

so go with something like

```
var fizzbuzz = function(start,stop) {
  var string = '';
  var addComma = false;
  for (var x=1;x <= stop; x++){
    addComma = false;
    if (x%3 == 0) {
        string += 'Fizz';
        addComma = true;
    }
    if (x%5 ==  0){
        string += 'Buzz';
        addComma = true;
    }
    if(addComma && x!== stop){
        string+=','
    }
  }
  return string;
};
```

This is not the best way to keep track of where to add a comma, but it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(let x = 0; x <=30; x++) {
if (x % 15 === 0) {
    console.log('Fizzbuzz')
} else if (x % 5 === 0) {
    console.log('Buzz')
} else if (x % 3 === 0) {
    console.log('Fizz')
} else {
    console.log(x)
}
```

}

this is how i dealt with it

Comment: The division by 15 should return ''Fizzbuzz'', not ''Fizz Buzz''

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your for loop

You have

```
for (var x=1;x <= stop; x++)
    var string =',';
```

being executed up until `x <= stop`.

Javascript allows you to avoid using brackets if you want to execute one line statements like so.

```
if (a===true)
    alert(a); // This is executed when a === true

alert(b); // This is always executed no matter what a is
```

Indentation here was to make a point but the if statement would execute everything until the first semicolon.

On the other hand if you wanted to perform multiple lines of code if `a === true` you would choose to use curly braces like so

```
// Alert a and alert b are only executed if a is true
if (a===true) {
    alert(a);
    alert(b);
}
```

The if statement would execute everything in the curly braces.

Its important to note that `return` stops execution and exits the function. Once you reach a return statement the loop will be exited. That is why you should return the whole string after the for loop.

This is a better implementation **but you should definitely try implementing it yourself**

```
var fizzbuzz = function(start,stop) {
    var string = '';

    for (var x=1;x <= stop; x++) {
        var status = x.toString(); //Each time the loop executes a new variable `status`is created and set to the value `x` for that loop.

        // x is checked as to whether it is divisible by 3 or 5 or both, if it is divisible its status is set to a that value
        if (x%3 === 0) {
            status = 'Fizz';
        }
        if (x%5 ===  0){
            status = 'Buzz';
        }
        if (x%5 === 0 && x%3 === 0){
            status = 'Fizzbuzz';
        }

        string += status; // Append status to the end

        if (x !== stop){ // If x is not equal to the value of stop add a comma
            string += ',';
        }
    }

    return string; //This returns the string value which has had statuses and commas appended to it.
};
```

Comment: This implementation gives me answer:
"Fizz buzz,Fizz buzz,Fizz,Fizz buzz,Buzz,Fizz,Fizz buzz,Fizz buzz,Fizz,Buzz,Fizz buzz,Fizz,Fizz buzz,Fizz buzz,Buzz,Fizz buzz,Fizz buzz,Fizz,Fizz buzz,Buzz,Fizz,Fizz buzz,Fizz buzz,Fizz,Buzz,Fizz buzz,Fizz,"

Comment: Serves me right for not actually checking it. Take a look at it again. Every value was fizz buzz because I was checking whether `(x % 3 && x % 5)` which is true for every number rather than whether `(x % 3 === 0 && x % 5 === 0)`. Fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/Lm44axy7/

Comment: That works perfect! Do you know a way I can remove a "," from the answer? I'm getting this after the last value. It ends like this: "22,23,Fizz,Buzz,26,Fizz,"

Comment: There are many good ways to do this. The problem is in the last line of the for loop which appends status and a comma no matter what. the way i would use (that avoids changing the structure) would be fixing the last line `string += status + ',';`. Instead you could say "if x === stop (which is the value stop passed in to the function) then append only status to string otherwise append status and a comma". This is good practice, use the fiddle I posted in my last comment and modify it to say this. If you get stuck press save at the top of JSFiddle and post the link here, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I tried to do what you said, by changing the last line. I might have broken it instead! Here's the link if you feel like helping me see what I did wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/Lm44axy7/5/

Comment: @micke So a few pointers. with the if (x === stop) statement every curly brace must end with a curly brace like so if (x === stop) { // contents }. Secondly you are changing the whole value of string (using the equals operator) rather than appending to the end (using the += operator). Finally you seem to be returning status instead of string. You should check out this fiddle which is a complete solution jsfiddle.net/oaep8umL I have also updated the main answer with this solution. Play around with it some more if you like and if you run in to any problems I can help

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with this: 
(1) The construct

```
for (var x=1;x <= 10; x++)
    statement;
otherstatement;
```

will execute statement 10 times before it executes other statement. Without braces, Javascript assumes that the next statement is the contents of the for loop;

(2) The string variable is redefined in every loop which gets rid of the preceding version, so the return statement only prints out the last value of string.

(3) The logic of the fizzBuzz if statements are wrong. If you follow this for a statement that divides by 15, it executes all three statements. The third iff statement is therefore completely redundant.

A solution would look like:

```
var fizzBuzz = function(x){
    if(x%15==0){
         return "Fizzbuzz";
    }
    if(x%3==0){
          return "Fizz";
    }
    if(x%5==0){
          return "Buzz";
    }
    return x;
    };

var mainFunction = function(start,stop){
    var str="";
    for(var i=start; i < stop; i++){
          str += fizzBuzz(i) + ", ";
    }
       return str;
    };
```

Note that the third if statement for %15 is necessary only if this version demands that you print Fizzbuzz, rather than FizzBuzz.

Comment: This solution gives me:

SyntaxError: missing variable name
 

var function(start,stop){

Comment: Sorry, I missed the name of the function in the declaration, and there were a couple of other syntax error. I am not really fluent enough to reliably right js in a text editor with zero syntax mistakes. Should have tried compiling it.